# How to create a generic method without specify 2nd generic type, for custom order like LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, func

Having a Model:

```
public class MyCustomObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //A lot of properties
}
```

And a query `queryableObjectsToOrder` where I need to order by a custom property.
The property name is stored as string can be `"Id"` or `"Description"`.

```
queryableObjectsToOrder.OrderBy(customSortCreatedInRuntime);
```

Then I created a generic method to build the Func to Order.

```
public Func<TSource, TResult> CreateCustomSort<TSource, TResult>(Type t, string fieldName)
{
    var propertyField = t.GetProperty(fieldName);
    if (propertyField != null)
    {
        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(t, "sel");
        var fieldProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExp, fieldName);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(fieldProp, parameterExp);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
    else
        return (obj) => { return default(TResult); };
}
```

I call it and works:

```
string propertyToOrder = "Id";

var customSortCreatedInRuntime = CreateCustomSort<MyCustomObject, int>(typeof(MyCustomObject), propertyToOrder);
var resultList = queryableObjectsToOrder.OrderBy(customSortCreatedInRuntime);
```

But if I change the string propertyToOrder to "Description", I need to change the signature of the call to the generic method to:

```
string propertyToOrder = "Description";

var customSortCreatedInRuntime = CreateCustomSort<MyCustomObject, string>(typeof(MyCustomObject), propertyToOrder);
```

This is a problem because I don't know the type of the property name stored as string.
How I can rewrite the method CreateCustomSort, to work without specifying the type TResult?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the compiler to statically validate the type safety an expression (in your case, a generic return type) with information available at runtime (in your case, the `string` argument).

But you can make it `dynamic`, if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

When I see questions like this, I always wonder: "why?", and "this smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)". What is preventing you from doing a regular typesafe lambda?

Anyway, the easiest way to do this is without building a lambda:

```
public Func<TSource, object> CreateCustomSort<TSource>(string fieldName)
{
    var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TSource)).Find(fieldName, false);
    if (prop != null)
        return (x) => prop.GetValue(x, null);
    else
        return (x) => null;
}
```

If you want to use an exact equivalent to a manually typed lambda expression, you need to do something more complex, like building a new `IQueryable` instance that includes the `OrderBy` expression. The below extension method does this:

```
public static class OrderByExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderByField<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, string fieldName, bool isAscending = true)
    {
        var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TSource)).Find(fieldName, false);
        if (prop == null)
            return query;

        var sourceExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "source");
        var propExpr = Expression.Property(sourceExpr, prop.Name);
        var selectorExpr = Expression.Lambda(propExpr, sourceExpr);
        string method = isAscending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { query.ElementType, selectorExpr.Body.Type };
        var orderByCallExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, query.Expression, selectorExpr);
        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(orderByCallExpr);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    var myCustomObjects = new[] {
        new MyCustomObject() { Id = 10, Description = "Hello" },
        new MyCustomObject() { Id = 2, Description = "SO" },
        new MyCustomObject() { Id = 42, Description = "Abcde" }
    };

    var result = myCustomObjects
        .AsQueryable()
        .OrderByField("Description");

    foreach (var r in result)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", r.Id, r.Description);
}
```

With output:

```
42 - Abcde
10 - Hello
2 - SO
```

**Note:**

Building these query expressions is expensive, you should cache the built expression in a cache per `TSource` (and have quite a few invocations) if you want to see any performance benefits of this far more complex piece of code.